# How to configure spring's RestTemplate to allow for http2 requests?

Tags: java, spring, http2

Is there any options in Spring's RestTemplate http client(or any other client) which allows to send HTTP2.0 requests?

Comment: Have you checked: https://vanwilgenburg.wordpress.com/2016/04/01/spring-boot-http2 already?

Comment: Yes. I've looked into it. But the article is published two years ago and i still believe that it's possible to find in-box solution. Is there any?)